# Magento 2 setup error

Tags: magento2, php

**I am trying to install Magento 2 after finish install all and composer, went to the browser http://url/setup and get error:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
    echo "You cannot run this from the command line." . PHP_EOL .
        "Run \"php bin/magento\" instead." . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}
try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

// For Setup Wizard we are using our customized error handler
$handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);

\Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require __DIR__ . '/config/application.config.php')->run();
```

**try to run from the command line getting:**

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in
>   /var/www/magento2/setup/config/states.extensionManager.config.php on
>   line 66

**I have change the memory_limit = 2048MB in the php.ini under

/etc/php/7.0/apache2 and made restart to the apache**
[image]

Comment: Tried to increase `memory_limit` in php.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't given PHP enough memory. You can check your current memory limit via `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

To increase the limit, edit your [php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558150/how-to-know-which-php-ini-is-used) file and find the `memory_limit`, or create it if you can't find it. Set it to something like `memory_limit = 2048M`, depending on your available resources. Magento is very memory intensive.

Comment: thank you for your reply,  I increased the limit in the php.ini but is same.

I should edit the php.ini under the /etc/php/7.0/apache2/ right?

Comment: Could you show result from `phpinfo()` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I changed the memory_limit to **2048MB** and not to **2048M**